# Sencha Ext.define Uses vs Requires

Tags: javascript, extjs

```
Ext.define('...', { 
    uses: ['...'],
});
```

and

```
Ext.define('...', {
    requires: ['...'],
});
```

I am a bit confused...Do they have common ground at all? When do we use one or the other?

Comment: FWIW, Mitchell Simoens has a good [blog post](https://sencha.guru/2015/05/21/requiring-classes/) about this topic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's pretty much covered by the documentation:

> Uses are optional class dependencies that are used by, but not
>   required by, a class. These can be loaded asynchronously and do not
>   have to be available for the class to be instantiated.

For example, if it's something your class instantiates Foo in the constructor, then it should be in `requires`.

If it instantiates Foo in some method that might get called later by the developer, it could go in `uses`.

Answer (score 7):

'requires' are needed to create a class, 'uses' are needed to create an object of that class.

The event sequence is:

- Ext.define is called
- 'requires' and 'uses' are enqueued to be loaded asynchronously
- class is created when all its 'requires' are loaded
- Ext.onReady listeners are called when all classes' 'requires' and 'uses' are loaded