# how uses "uses" attribute in Ext.define?

Tags: extjs4

How use "uses" attribute in Ext.define ? 
Please example

I could find on the topic only [Sencha Ext.define Uses vs Requires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050728/sencha-ext-define-uses-vs-requires)

Answer (score 2):

```
Ext.define('Mother', {
    uses: ['Child'],
    giveBirth: function() {
        // This code might, or might not work:
        // return new Child();

        // Instead use Ext.create() to load the class at the spot if not loaded already:
        return Ext.create('Child');
    }
});
```

List of optional classes to load together with this class. These aren't neccessarily loaded before this class is created, but are guaranteed to be available before Ext.onReady listeners are invoked.